# Show User Role On Front End Of Account Page

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to allow customers to change their role on their WordPress account page and all works very well functionality wise except what is being shown on the front end. When they come to change their role, the option selected is always "Select an option..." rather than the actual role that they are designated to (such as Example 1). I have excluded some roles (such as Administrator) as I only want to show them certain roles. What do i change in the below code to fix this and show their current role?

```
            function iconic_get_account_fields() {

            return apply_filters( 'iconic_account_fields', array(

            'first_name'                 => array(

            'type'                 => 'text',

            'label'                => __( 'First Name', 'iconic' ),

            'hide_in_account'      => true,

            'hide_in_admin'        => true,

            'hide_in_checkout'     => true,

            'hide_in_registration' => false,

            'required'             => true,

            ),

            'last_name'                  => array(

            'type'                 => 'text',

            'label'                => __( 'Last Name', 'iconic' ),

            'hide_in_account'      => true,

            'hide_in_admin'        => true,

            'hide_in_checkout'     => true,

            'hide_in_registration' => false,

            'required'             => true,

            ),

            'role'                  => array(

            'type'    => 'select',

            'label'   => __( 'Franking Machine Model', 'iconic' ),

            'hide_in_account'      => false,

            'hide_in_admin'        => true,

            'hide_in_registration' => true,

            'hide_in_checkout'     => true,

            'options' => array(

            '' => __( 'Select an option...', 'iconic' ),

            'example_1_customer'  => __( 'Example 1', 'iconic' ),

            'example_2_customer'  => __( 'Example 2', 'iconic' ),

            'example_3_customer'  => __( 'Example 3', 'iconic' ),

            'other_customer'  => __( 'Other', 'iconic' ),
        ),
    ),
) );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Get current role of user using below function

```
function get_current_user_role(){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $roles = $current_user->roles;
    return $roles[0];
}
```

**SOLUTION #1**

Pass it to **woocommerce_form_field($key, $args, $value)** function , consider below example ,

```
    $fields = iconic_get_account_fields();
    $role = get_current_user_role();
    foreach ($fields as $key => $field_args) {
        if ($key == 'role') {
            woocommerce_form_field($key, $field_args, $role);
        } else {
            woocommerce_form_field($key, $field_args);
        }
    }
```

**SOLUTION #2**

Make modification of function you shared as below , I have added 'value' argument.

```
function iconic_get_account_fields() {
    return apply_filters('iconic_account_fields', array(
        'first_name' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => __('First Name', 'iconic'),
            'hide_in_account' => true,
            'hide_in_admin' => true,
            'hide_in_checkout' => true,
            'hide_in_registration' => false,
            'required' => true,
        ),
        'last_name' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => __('Last Name', 'iconic'),
            'hide_in_account' => true,
            'hide_in_admin' => true,
            'hide_in_checkout' => true,
            'hide_in_registration' => false,
            'required' => true,
        ),
        'role' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'label' => __('Franking Machine Model', 'iconic'),
            'hide_in_account' => false,
            'hide_in_admin' => true,
            'hide_in_registration' => true,
            'hide_in_checkout' => true,
            'options' => array(
                '' => __('Select an option...', 'iconic'),
                'example_1_customer' => __('Example 1', 'iconic'),
                'example_2_customer' => __('Example 2', 'iconic'),
                'example_3_customer' => __('Example 3', 'iconic'),
                'other_customer' => __('Other', 'iconic'),
            ),
            'value' => apply_filters('selectedrole','')  // added new arg
        ),
 ));

add_filter('selectedrole', 'get_current_user_role');
```

Let me know which work best for you.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks so much, the second solution has worked a treat and does exactly what i wanted it to do. Added the function get_current_user_role then the filter helped fix the issue. Perfect thanks!